# Mirror Table in Snowflake from Region A( Mumbai) to Region B (Seoul)

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

I have a current use case where my data is landing in a data lake built on a snowflake in DB1. From the Source DB (DB1) I want to do selective replication

Table_in to a Snowflake instance provisioned in Mumbai.
Table_us to a Snowflake instance provisioned in the US.
and so on.

I know we have replication available at a database level.
But I want to know how to do it at table level.

If there are strategies available that might help me achieve the outcome.
Both Source and Destination are Snowflake instances

*Note:- This is the business requirement and the requirement can not be altered.

Answer (score 0):

The only Snowflake functionality that makes data from one region available in another region is replication, and that works at the database level - as you’ve stated.

Doing this with an external tool or code is perfectly possible but recommending tools is against the Stackoverflow guidelines - google will quickly provide you with a large number of options